# Size of string in message function in R

Tags: r, windows-7-x64

There seems to be a limit on the size of the string used in message. The following only prints until number 1859 (Using R v3.1.3 on 64 bit Win7 machine)

```
message(paste(seq(1,2000),collapse = "-"))
```

while

```
cat(paste(seq(1,2000),collapse = "-"))
```

prints it all. Is this a bug?

Comment: Using R 3.2.0 on a linux machine prints it all

Comment: reproducible on 3.1.2, 64-bit MacOS

Comment: I use message to print the log from C++ code run in a R package. Given a verbose option this can be quite large.

Comment: You can have your c++ code to the logging (but that would go to a different stream).  But you should probably think about a 'message chopper' that parcels it out into several shorter chunks.  Assuming 'unlimited' string length for logging is ... maybe too much.  Remember 80 char limits?  ;-)

Comment: I mainly use the verbose option for debugging so implementing a 'message chopper' may be overkill. Anyway the current hack is just to use cat instead even though some say that message is more consistent.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel RJDBC query error message is a nice example of the utility of big messages. For big queries created by scripts, you can't see where is the error. I applied tryCatch to `cat` the error instead of `message` it, but IMHO it's very inelegant.

Comment: I am not sure if it is relevant but `message()` uses stderr, while `cat()` uses stdout. I can reproduce this with R 3.4.0 on Win10

Answer (score 1):

There's a good solution in this question:

[avoid string printed to console getting truncated (in RStudio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800475/avoid-string-printed-to-console-getting-truncated-in-rstudio)

As it suggests, if you're using RStudio, just go to Global Options -> Code -> Display -> Limit length of lines displayed in the console to:

And change the value to zero. It works for me.