# Avoid truncation using mongo.find.all() with rmongodb in R

Tags: mongodb, findall, truncated, rmongodb

I want to use mongo.find.all() to get all the records in one collection. However, I find certain fields in the results are truncated. Something like the following,

```
.....
$onefiled
[1] xxxxxxxx... <truncated>
......
```

I wonder how I can avoid this issue and get the full content of that field? I couldn't find a parameter in mongo.find.all() to control this.

Answer (score 0):

Just find out that it is not the problem of rmongodb. It is only a display issue with Rstudio. I actually got the full content, but Rstudio only displayed the first 1000 chars of that field (in string format).

I solved it by re-ajust the display options of Rstudio, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800475/avoid-string-printed-to-console-getting-truncated-in-rstudio).