# dput output truncated too early

Tags: r

When using dput (or dump) to share objects, I get output that is truncated very early. This also happens when dumping to a file.

I haven't been able to find the setting that governs this, but this didn't happen to me in the past and I'm not aware of having changed any settings. Unfortunately, I don't recall when exactly this started happening.

`dput(rnorm(20))`

> c(0.178996565881475, -0.0979247582427519, -0.722093025014011, 
>   0.88981201078104, 0.997508460579067, 0.416896899499781, 1.09045614607683, 
>     ...

I'm using Rstudio 1.1.442, I don't know if that is relevant. [This setting in Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800475/avoid-string-printed-to-console-getting-truncated-in-rstudio?noredirect=1&lq=1) does not affect the truncation of `dput`.

Comment: What does `getAnywhere(dput)` tell you about the location of `dput`?  Truncation of output looks like something the standard `dput` just doesn't do.

Comment: It's `base::dput`, nothing funky as far as I can tell.

Comment: Very weird.  What version of R are you using?

Comment: 3.4.4 but had the same problem in 3.4.3 and I think earlier.