# How Do I View All Output in Rstudio Console When the Output is Large

Tags: r, rstudio

Take for instance,

```
rnorm(9999999)
```

produces a very large output in the console that even if I scroll up to the last limit, I can not see all output.

I prefer solution(s) that will not require me to save the output.

Comment: `options(max.print = big_number)`

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `page()`?

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/more-than-1000-lines-output-in-r-studio-console/3288/9 suggests `rstudioapi::writeRStudioPreference("console_max_lines", <size>)` might do it, if I've understood you correctly (I haven't tried it - it needs RStudio 1.3.688, which I don't have at work).  Probably need to set `max.print` too, as suggested by Ronak Shah

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
oo <- options(max.print=2e+06)  ## set and store defaults
options(oo)  ## restore defaults
```

for two million rows to display (9999999 / 5).

In addition consider the lines cut-off. In RGui it may be configured using *[Edit] > [GUI preferences]* (see image below).

[image]

There are similar options for RStudio, consult [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36801237/6574038) for more information.